# spree get variant option value

Tags: product, spree, variant

I created products and their variants. Variants have options size and color.

I'm trying to read all variants and their color names:

```
variants = product.variants_including_master.active(current_currency).includes([:option_values])

variants.each do |variant|
  # here I want to read variant options color and size
  # something like:  variant.option_values['color']
end
```

I've seen a lot of stuff on internet and can't get anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my situation with this:

```
      variants = product.variants_including_master.active(current_currency).includes([:option_values])

      variants.each do |variant|

        color = variant.option_values.select { |a| a.option_type.id == 2 }.first

        if not color.nil? then
          @product_colors << color[:name]
        end
      end
```